# How to get facebook album photos id and time using php?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm new in php. I make below two code to get `facebook` album photos id and create time. But its not working and don't showing me result/ID, only showing me blank page.

Here is my two code with $json and $array output.

Code 1;

```
<?php 
$token="<token>"; 
$data = file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/106097030098624/photos?fields=id&access_token=$token");
$json = json_decode($data); 
echo $json->id;
echo $json->created_time;
?>
```

Code 1 Output: using `var_dump($json);`

```
object(stdClass)#1 (2) {
  ["data"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#2 (2) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(15) "160246594547781"
      ["created_time"]=>
      string(24) "2017-08-04T18:09:13+0000"
    }
    [1]=>
    object(stdClass)#3 (2) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(15) "160246581214449"
      ["created_time"]=>
      string(24) "2017-08-04T18:09:12+0000"
    }
    [2]=>
    object(stdClass)#4 (2) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(15) "160246587881115"
      ["created_time"]=>
      string(24) "2017-08-04T18:09:13+0000"
    }
  }
  ["paging"]=>
  object(stdClass)#5 (1) {
    ["cursors"]=>
    object(stdClass)#6 (2) {
      ["before"]=>
      string(20) "MTYwMjQ2NTk0NTQ3Nzgx"
      ["after"]=>
      string(20) "MTYwMjQ2NTg3ODgxMTE1"
    }
  }
}
```

Code 2:

```
<?php
$token="<token>";
$data = file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/106097030098624/photos?fields=id&access_token=$token");
$array = json_decode($data, true);
echo $array['data']['id'];
echo $array['data']['created_time'];
?>
```

Code 2 Output: Using `var_dump($array);`

```
array(2) {
  ["data"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(15) "160246594547781"
      ["created_time"]=>
      string(24) "2017-08-04T18:09:13+0000"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(15) "160246581214449"
      ["created_time"]=>
      string(24) "2017-08-04T18:09:12+0000"
    }
    [2]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(15) "160246587881115"
      ["created_time"]=>
      string(24) "2017-08-04T18:09:13+0000"
    }
  }
  ["paging"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["cursors"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["before"]=>
      string(20) "MTYwMjQ2NTk0NTQ3Nzgx"
      ["after"]=>
      string(20) "MTYwMjQ2NTg3ODgxMTE1"
    }
  }
}
```

Please help me to solve this issue.thanks

Comment: do `var_dump($json)` and `var_dump($array);` in code 1,2 just after `json_decode()` line and see what output is coming?Show us

Comment: i edited and added output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***For first one you need to do:-***

```
<?php 
$token="<token>"; 
$data = file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/106097030098624/photos?fields=id&access_token=$token");
$json = json_decode($data); 
foreach($array.data as $arr){
  echo $arr.id; echo PHP_EOL; // you can use `echo "<br/>";`
  echo $arr.created_time;echo PHP_EOL;// you can use `echo "<br/>";`
 }
?>
```

***For second-one you can use:-***

```
<?php
$token="<token>";
$data = file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/106097030098624/photos?
fields=id&access_token=$token");
$array = json_decode($data, true);
foreach($array['data'] as $arr){
  echo $arr['id']; echo PHP_EOL; // you can use `echo "<br/>";`
  echo $arr['created_time'];echo PHP_EOL;// you can use `echo "<br/>";`
 }
?>
```

Output:- https://eval.in/841721

Comment: @MasudRana  please up-vote the answer too.glad to help you :):)